# Tomcat SPNEGO filter - REMOTE_USER in access log

Tags: tomcat

With the Tomcat (8.0.15) [access log valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve), the default logging pattern is '%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b'

I am using the [SPNEGO](http://spnego.sourceforge.net) filter to authenticate users.

The hello.jsp file with a simple `request.getRemoteUser()` does show my Windows username so the filter is working fine.

So I thought the %u would expand to the CGI variable REMOTE_USER but it just shows a blank.

I even tried using %{REMOTE_USER}i and %{REMOTE_USER}s and %{REMOTE_USER}r  but none of them end up showing the value in the access log.

I enabled the [Extended Access Log Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Extended_Access_Log_Valve) by adding

`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ExtendedAccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="extended_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="c-ip x-H(remoteUser) date time cs-method cs-uri cs-uri-query cs-uri-stem sc-status bytes" />`

in `conf/server.xml` but still no go.

Here is what I get in my extended access log

`xx.xx.xx.xx - 2014-11-25 19:55:43 GET /hello.jsp - /hello.jsp 200 102`

and in my access log

`xx.xx.xx.xx - - - [25/Nov/2014:14:55:43 -0500] "GET /hello.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 102`

What am I missing? Is this a timing issue? The filter is setting REMOTE_USER *after* the access log entry is written?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'm betting that, yes, the logging is happening before the filter is applied.  This happens when using Spring Security as well.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31350895/225217