# How Tomcat is Picking remote user that was authenticated

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, logback

If i enable tomcat access logs through logback as below

```
logback.access:
  enabled: true

compile group: 'net.rakugakibox.spring.boot', name: 'logback-access-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.5.0'
```

configuration as below

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="${LOG_FILE_LOCATION:-/var/log/RSP}/${HOST_NAME}}"/>
    <appender name="ACCESS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${LOG_HOME}/reservation_access.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/reservation_access-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%h %l %u [%{TraceId}i] %t "%r" %s %b %D</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS" />

</configuration>
```

it's working fine, but i am not able to understand how it is picking %u, in [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html) it's mentioned as `Remote user that was authenticated` so how tomcat knows who is authenticated user or can any one provide the source code of how these access logs will be generated.(i have gone through the basic article [what is Access Log Valve](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-access-log-configuration-example/))

And if i enable access logs by using spring boot properties as below

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern: '%h %l %u [%{TraceId}i] %t "%r" %s %b %D'
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix: reservation_access
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled: true
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory: /var/log/RSP/
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix: .log
```

then %u is not working,

- so what is difference between these two versions?
- when access logs will be printed for each request i.e after executing all filters or as soon as the request reaches to server it will be printed ?

  Thanks

Comment: Evidently Tomcat logging is happening before Spring Security's `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` decorates the request . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31350895/225217

Answer (score 0):

`logback-access-spring-boot-starter` reads the value for `%u` from `HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`.

In the Spring world `HttpServletRequest.remoteUser()` will typically be populated by Spring Security.

Comment: then in that case if i enable using this property `server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled: true` when %u is not coming ?

Comment: Perhaps `HttpServletRequest.remoteUser` is not populated.